# Does AutoPlace Signature work in Sandbox environment?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying out DocuSign's AutoPlace feature in sandbox environment. For some reason, DocuSign is not finding my anchorStrings in the document. My reference is https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/autoplace#use-autoplace-to-dynamically-place-signing-fields

Does AutoPlace Signature work in Sandbox environment?

Answer (score 1):

AutoPlace feature works in DocuSign sandbox environment. The error was in my workflow. 
My workflow was:
 create draft envelope -> add documents --> add recipients --> send envelope. 
I included the tab information while adding the recipients.  I thought if I included the tabs information along with recipients, the tabs would get created, and I was wrong. 
The correct workflow is:
create draft envelope -> add documents -> add recipients -> add tabs -> send envelope.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the eg-01 series of examples on http://github.com/docusign -- there is an example repo for each language.

The examples include envelope creation with Autoplace (anchor text) used to position the tabs.

Your workflow works fine.

You can also create the envelope with its documents, recipients, tabs, etc all at one time--this is the pattern used by the examples.